# Error: Could not find or load main class on running the java file

Tags: java, windows, jar, classpath

When I compile the following, it compiles and creates a .class file. It works

```
javac -classpath abc.jar Abc.java
```

But when I run the following:

```
java -classpath abc.jar Abc
```

It gives this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class
```

I am using a cmd on windows 7. It works with a basic helloworld example but not with others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it overrides classpath so again you will have to add current directory to classpath

```
java -classpath abc.jar:. Abc
```

Comment: tried exact same thing but did not work.. same error. Can you tell me the list of all commands?

Comment: oh for windows try `;` i.e `java -classpath abc.jar;. Abc`